# Bind UserControl Property to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an UserContol Combination of Country Code Combobox and A number Textbox.

In my Window, I have 2 UserControl (Primary Phone Number and Secondary Phone Number)

Here is my Model

```
     public class ContactNumber
    {
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string phone_code { get; set; }
        public int is_active { get; set; }
        public List<Country> country { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is My UserControl XAML

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--ComboBox for Country-->
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxMerged}" x:Name="cmbCountry"></ComboBox>
            <TextBlock Text="|" FontSize="{StaticResource fontSize30}" Foreground="{StaticResource LightSilverBrush}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-5,0,0">
            </TextBlock>
            <!--TextBox for Number-->
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxWithDropDown}" 
                     Text="{Binding ContactNumber.Number,ElementName=ContactWindow,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     x:Name="txtContactNumber" TextChanged="txtContactNumber_TextChanged" Width="240" Grid.Column="2">
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
```

Here is my Control Code Behind

```
   public ContactNumber ContactNumber
        {
            get { return (ContactNumber)GetValue(ContactNumberProperty); }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(ContactNumberProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ContactNumber.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContactNumberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ContactNumber", typeof(ContactNumber), typeof(ContactNumberWithCountryCode),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                SetText));

        private static void SetText(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContactNumberWithCountryCode contactNumberWithCountryCode=d as ContactNumberWithCountryCode;
            if (contactNumberWithCountryCode!=null)
            {
                contactNumberWithCountryCode.txtContactNumber.Text = (e.NewValue as ContactNumber).Number.ToString();
            }
        }

        public ContactNumberWithCountryCode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtContactNumber_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContactNumber.Number = txtContactNumber.Text;

        }
```

This is my Main Window XAMl

```
                <usercontrols:ContactNumberWithCountryCode ContactNumber="{Binding PrimaryContactNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="PracticePhoneNumber"  Margin="0,15,0,0" ></usercontrols:ContactNumberWithCountryCode>
                <usercontrols:ContactNumberWithCountryCode ContactNumber="{Binding SecondryContactNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="SecondaryPracticePhoneNumber"  Margin="0,15,0,0" ></usercontrols:ContactNumberWithCountryCode>
```

Here is my View Model Code

```
   private ContactNumber primaryContactNumber;

        public ContactNumber PrimaryContactNumber
        {
            get { return primaryContactNumber; }
            set 
            { 
                primaryContactNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PrimaryContactNumber");
            }
        }

        private ContactNumber secondryContactNumber;

        public ContactNumber SecondryContactNumber
        {
            get { return secondryContactNumber; }
            set
            {
                secondryContactNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SecondryContactNumber");
            }
        }
```

My goal is to fill ViewModel Property on Text Or Combobox Value Change.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `ElementName=ContactWindow` in the TextBox.Text Binding in the UserControl's XAML doesn't seem to make sense. It should be `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`. In addition, the ContactNumber class also needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, while `txtContactNumber_TextChanged` is redundant.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, I did what exactly What you suggested   Added     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"  to text box but i am getting  Exception "The value supplied on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception. ' line number '24' and line position '22'. "

Comment: You should of course keep the Binding's Path: `Text="{Binding ContactNumber.Number, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: As another note, the SetText callback method is also redundant. It does nothing sensible.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, Thanks for the suggestion It Worked!! Thanks. Can you help me to get Combobox Selected Value?